# Segmentation fault using fscanf and malloc

Tags: c

```
void fill_garage(Car** garage, char* cars, int* size)
 43 {
 44     int i;
 45     FILE* file=fopen(cars,"r");
 46     fscanf(file,"%d",size);
 47     *garage=malloc(sizeof(Car)**size);
 48     printf("%d",*size);
 49     for(i=0;i<*size;i++)
 50     {
 51         (*garage)[i].make=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING_LEN);
 52         (*garage)[i].model=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING_LEN);
 53         fscanf(file,"%d%s%s%d",(*garage)[i].year,(*garage)[i].make,(*garage)[i].model,(*garage)[i].miles);
 54     }
 55     fclose(file);
 56 }
```

I am getting a segmentation fault on this code, gdb returns that the garage[i]->make line is the reason for this but I can not figure out why this line would case a seg fault.

Comment: `garage=&carsPtr;` should be `*garage = carsPtr;` . You want to tell the calling function about `carsPtr`.

Comment: check the return value of `fscanf` . Check `*size` is what you think it is. You never allocated any memory to `carsPtr[i].model` either.

Comment: Basically you need to *debug your code*. If you can't use a debugger then use `printf` statements to make sure everything is as it should be at each step of the program.

Comment: also the `equals` function is wrong; you want to check if the two strings have the same letters in them; not check if they both inhabit the same memory address.

Comment: In `drive_cars` `fscanf(file,"%d%s%s%d",&year[i],&make[i],&model[i],&miles[i]);` is wrong, think about what `&make[i]` is. You have so many serious errors in this code, I think you need to scale down and start smaller. Get a basic version working and free of errors first, and then gradually add new functionality.

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: You have just edited the question to change the code. Is there still a problem?

Comment: yes I can not figure out why this is seg faulting in the fill_garage function. Gdb keeps saying that it is the garage[i]->make line.

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson if you are unsure about the file format, read from the file using `fgets()` then use `sscanf()` to retrieve information from the line, that way it is easier to control the input.

Comment: OP, completely deleting your previous code versions is bad manners since it renders answers incomprehensible.

Comment: Does it output the value of  `*size` correctly?

Comment: Yes it does now I am working on another part where I have logic errors. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf` with `%d` format requires a *pointer* to `int` as an argument. You are apparently trying to pass the `int` itself instead of a pointer

```
fscanf(file,"%d%s%s%d", 
  &(*garage)[i].year,
  (*garage)[i].make,
  (*garage)[i].model,
  &(*garage)[i].miles);
```

Note the placement of `&` operators in arguments of `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in using `garage[i]->`. You should be using `(*garage)[i].` instead. With `garage[i]`, you're not traversing the allocated array, but rather the memory in direct proximity to the `garage` pointer, and then trying to write it, which most probably causes the segfault.

And now you have changed your code to pass values instead of pointers to `fscanf`. You should use `&(*garage)[i].year` and `&(*garage)[i].miles`.

Comment: but when its called in main and then passed by reference it doesn't get initialized then?? Also when it gets called in the first fscanf before the loop it reads an integer value out of the file

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson: if it doesn't get initialized, it can very well have even a negative value, since using an uninitialized variable is *undefined behaviour*. Even if this isn't what caused the error, you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: Where would I have to initialize it then? Because the file that is opened has it on the first line

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson: Wherever you like to, it's your code. Oh, and I found another error, I'll update my post now

Comment: Hmmm well it isn't causing the seg fault because when I explicated declared it as a value and commented out the code and bumped the file pointer so it would skip the size line it still seg faulted

Comment: Well garage is a double pointer, so I would need to have a go between for garage and the actual structs correct? Like something for garage to point to which would then be all the structs

Comment: I have uploaded the updated code however it is still seg faulting

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson: are you sure you've properly modified your `fscanf` code?

Comment: It is still seg faulting I originally had the address operator on the last 2 struct arguments in the fscanf. How would I properly modify then?

Comment: Not the *last two*, should be the first and the last. @AndreyT's answer has the whole code for the call.

Comment: Yeah my bad that is what I meant I updated it to that still seg fault.